How can I fix numerous gaps in doors and windows in my apartment?
In my apartment, almost all of the doors are not sealed properly. These large gaps exist which allow in bugs. Also occasionally if this front patio door is closed but not locked, the force of the air suction when closing the back door will actually open this patio door; we’ll come back to our apartment with one of the doors just hanging open. It’s very hard to close the doors all the way as well.
The landlord explained that the doors were installed in the heat and this has led to warping of the frame but that it should “settle in” at some point. I just want the entire house to be sealed up and no more ants getting in or heat/cool air escaping.


Please show us more. The problem doesn't lie on this site of the door.

Apply weather stripping to the frame. Exact type will depend on gap to be closed.
